# Switch selectedState between three UIButton on the same tab

Tags: ios, xcode, uibutton

**I have 3 UIButton on the same tab.**

**The problem :** 
When I click on button1, button2 and button3 all of them got selected; however what I want is when I select (for example) button2, the other buttons be unselected (like radio buttons on html).
Any idea on how I can solve this issue ?

**Here is my code :**

> ```
> - (IBAction)button1:(UIButton *)sender {
>     sender.selected = !sender.selected;
>  }
> - (IBAction)button2:(UIButton *)sender {
>  sender.selected = !sender.selected;
>  }
> - (IBAction)button3:(UIButton *)sender {
>  sender.selected = !sender.selected;
>  }
> ```

Comment: on click of the button set selected and set others to unselect in the same method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of straightforward solutions. Maybe they are not optimal, but you can use them:

**First solution:**

Link your buttons with corresponding properties:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *button1;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *button2;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *button3;
```

In each action change the *selected* property for each button:

```
- (IBAction)button1Clicked:(UIButton *)sender {
    _button1.selected = YES;
    _button2.selected = NO;
    _button3.selected = NO;
}
```

**Second solution:**

Add all your buttons in NSArray:

```
NSArray *buttonsArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: button1, button2, button3, nil];
```

Then link all the buttons with one action:

```
- (IBAction)buttonClicked:(UIButton *)sender {
    for (UIButton *btn in _buttonsArray) {
        if (btn == sender)
            btn.selected = YES;
        else
            btn.selected = NO;
    }
}
```

Don't forget to make your NSArray accessible for all the methods of the class, for example by creating a corresponding property:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) NSArray *buttonsArray;
```

**Third solution:**

You can change the tag property for each button (through Interface Builder or in code):

```
_button1.tag = 1;
_button2.tag = 2;
_button3.tag = 3;
```

Then link all the buttons with one action (just like in previous example):

```
- (IBAction)buttonClicked:(UIButton *)sender {
    if (sender.tag == 1) {
        _button1.selected = YES;
        _button2.selected = NO;
        _button3.selected = NO;
    } else if (sender.tag == 2) {
        _button1.selected = NO;
        _button2.selected = YES;
        _button3.selected = NO;
    } else if (sender.tag == 3) {
        _button1.selected = NO;
        _button2.selected = NO;
        _button3.selected = YES;
    } 
}
```

**Fourth solution:** (by @velmurugan-s)

Use one action for all the buttons and set their default state to *selected = NO*:

```
- (IBAction)buttonClicked:(UIButton *)sender {
    _button1.selected = NO;
    _button2.selected = NO;
    _button3.selected = NO;

    sender.selected = YES;
}
```

**Summary:**

I'd recommend you to use the second solution as the most optimal one.

Comment: Thank you so much for you help ! I am trying now with the first solution, but it says in this line *button1.selected = YES;* that button1 is an undeclared identifier, why ?

Comment: Have you linked your buttons with properties? Just ctrl+drag each button to corresponding property.

Comment: It works now ! I replaced button1 with _button1 and it is fine now ! Thank you so much for the help !! you saved my day !!

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is connect button1,button2,button3 to same button123 in interface section give them appropriate tags

`- (IBAction)button123:(UIButton *)sender;`

In its description use below code

```
- (IBAction)button123:(UIButton *)sender {

if (sender.tag == 111)
{
    sender.selected = !sender.selected;

    if (sender.selected)
    {
        self.button2.selected = NO;
        self.button3.selected = NO;


    }

}
else if (sender.tag == 222)
{
    sender.selected = !sender.selected;

    if (sender.selected)
    {
       self.button1.selected = NO;
        self.button3.selected = NO;

    }


}
else if (sender.tag == 333)
{
    sender.selected = !sender.selected;

    if (sender.selected)
    {
      self.button1.selected = NO;
        self.button2.selected = NO;

    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, I really appreciate it, @etolstoy solution worked with. So I haven't tried your solution. Thank you anyway !!

Answer (score 0):

You had change the selected sate for a button that you have selected,You need to change all other button state too.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (IBAction)button1:(UIButton *)sender {
    btn1.selected = YES;
    btn2.selected = NO;
    btn3.selected = NO;

 }
- (IBAction)button2:(UIButton *)sender {

    btn1.selected = NO;
    btn2.selected = YES;
    btn3.selected = NO;
 }
- (IBAction)button3:(UIButton *)sender {
    btn1.selected = NO;
    btn2.selected = NO;
    btn3.selected = YES;
 }
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, I really appreciate it, @etolstoy solution worked with. So I haven't tried your solution. Thank you anyway !!